# Tricks for deserialize this xml element

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

A legacy application transmits data as xml elements.

```
<frame>
<reply>
    <id>value_id</id>
    <resultCode>value</resultCode>
    <readSampleIDs>
        <returnValue>
            <Sample>
                <SampleID> value_SampleID </SampleID>
                <SamplePC> value_SamplePC </SamplePC>
                <antennaName> value_antennaName </antennaName>
                <channel> value_channel </channel>
                <power> value_power </power>
                <polarization> value_polarization </polarization>
                <inventoried> value_inventoried </inventoried>
            </Sample>
            …
            <Sample>
            …
            </Sample>
        </returnValue>
    </readSampleIDs>
</reply>
```

Currently the information is extracted parsing the string word by word.
I think that xml element can be deserialized into an object directly with **XmlSerializer** but I have some doubts on how to do it.
The element **frame** contains only one **reply**. Do I really need two different classes ?
Inside **returnValue** there can be zero or more **Sample**. In my class what is the correct type, **List<Sample>** or **Sample[]** ? Is there a real difference between the two options during deserialization ?
Most fields inside **Sample** are optional. How do I model this ?

When an object is serialized with **XmlSerializer** information about xml version and additional attributes on root element are automatically added such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<PurchaseOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.cpandl.com">
```

They are not present in my example code so I'm afraid deserialization can complain about it and possibly fail.

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: Upload your XML to http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/, let it generate classes for you, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml contains a namespace (like in your example) then you can use these classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sample")]
public class Sample
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SampleID")]
    public string SampleID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SamplePC")]
    public string SamplePC { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "antennaName")]
    public string AntennaName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "channel")]
    public string Channel { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "power")]
    public string Power { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "polarization")]
    public string Polarization { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "inventoried")]
    public string Inventoried { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "readSampleIDs")]
public class ReadSampleIDs
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "returnValue")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Sample")]
    public List<Sample> Sample { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "reply", Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
public class Reply
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "resultCode")]
    public string ResultCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "readSampleIDs")]
    public ReadSampleIDs ReadSampleIDs { get; set; }
}
```

If you are only interested in node **reply** and this is the only one. You can deserialize only this node:

```
XNamespace loNameSpace = "http://www.cpandl.com";
XDocument loDoc = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.TransmitsData);

var loReplyElement = loDoc.Element(loNameSpace.GetName("PurchaseOrder"))
    .Element(loNameSpace.GetName("frame"))
    .Element(loNameSpace.GetName("reply"));

using (var loReader = loReplyElement.CreateReader())
{
    var loSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Reply));
    var loReply = (Reply)loSerializer.Deserialize(loReader);
    Console.WriteLine(loReply.Id);
}
```